# Xamarian/MonoTouch: Convert System.Exception to NSException

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm integrating Flurry Analytics into my Xamarin/MonoTouch iOS App with the following binding:
https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/FlurryAnalytics

Now, I'd like to use Flurry Analytic's error logging:

```
void LogError (string errorID, string message, NSException exception);
```

I'm catching exceptions with this code in my AppDelegate:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) => { /**/ };
```

However, as far as I can figure out Xamarin/MonoTouch has converted all NSExceptions to System.Exception.

Can System.Exception be converted back to NSException so I can use it in the LogError routine?

Or is it possible to catch NSExceptions in a Xamarin/MonoTouch project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the UncaughtExceptionHandler in the AppDelegate class? They have a sample on the github page you mentioned.

```
static void UncaughtExceptionHandler(IntPtr handle)
        {

            var exception = new NSException(handle);
            FA.Flurry.LogError("3584", exception.Reason, exception);

            Console.WriteLine(@"Got an exception...{0} -- {1}", exception.Name, exception.Reason);
        }
```

https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/blob/master/FlurryAnalytics/sample/Xamarin.FlurryAnalyticsSample/AppDelegate.cs

Edit:
The sample also shows how to log a System.Exception in the [AnalyticsViewController.cs](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/blob/master/FlurryAnalytics/sample/Xamarin.FlurryAnalyticsSample/ViewControllers/AnalyticsViewController.cs)

Comment: Are you sure the UncaughtExceptionHandler static method should work? I don't catch any exceptions there. They have commented out some DllImport code that I think was intended for catching the exception. However, uncommenting it won't compile.

In the other link, they create a new NSError and feed Flurry Analytics with the error message + this new error object. That might be an option. But it would be really nice to see the stack information from the original Exception in Flurry.

Comment: As demoed in the second link, a System.Exception could also be logged. Just concatenate ex.Message with ex.StackTrace while logging.